# WPF-How to load two different mousedown event in user control to mainwindow?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

If you can help me,I'll be happy :)
I have two border in usercontrol is name UserControlMainScreen.And border's have mousedown event.

**UserControlMainScreen.xaml:**

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Name="Grid_MainButtons">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Name="brd_BTES"  Grid.Column="1" MouseDown="UserControlMainScreen_brd_BTES_MouseDown" CornerRadius="10"  >
                <TextBlock Name="txtb_BTES" Text="BTES"></TextBlock>
             </Border>
            <Border Name="brd_SBE" Grid.Column="3" MouseDown="UserControlMainScreen_brd_SBE_MouseDown" CornerRadius="10" >
                <TextBlock Name="txtb_SBE" Text="SBE"></TextBlock>
            </Border>
</Grid>
```

**Problem**:I want that when I click one of brd_SBE/brd_BTES,different mousedown event should occur(like as UserControlMainScreen_brd_SBE_MouseDown and UserControlMainScreen_brd_BTES_MouseDown).But when I click one of the borders,events occur in UserControlMainScreen_brd_SBE_MouseDown only.

**MainWindow.cs**:

```
UserControlMainScreen uAnaEkran = new UserControlMainScreen();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            uAnaEkran.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(UserControlMainScreen_brd_SBE_MouseDown);
            uAnaEkran.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(UserControlMainScreen_brd_BTES_MouseDown);
        }
//some codes..

void UserControlMainScreen_brd_SBE_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //if (sender == uAnaEkran.Grid_MainButtons.Children[1])

                brd_Menu2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                brd_Menu1.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(BaseUriHelper.GetBaseUri(this), "Images/TopButton1Passive2.png")));
                brd_Menu2.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(BaseUriHelper.GetBaseUri(this), "Images/TopButton2Active2.png")));

                var bc = new BrushConverter();
                txtb_Menu1.Foreground = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#FF0A2C62");
                txtb_Menu2.Text = uAnaEkran.txtb_SBE.Text.ToString() + " MODÜLÜ";

                e.Handled = true;

        }
        void UserControlMainScreen_brd_BTES_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("btes");
        }
```

So how can I solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Please make your question more clearer.

Comment: @ViVi thnks your reply.Can u check again Problem?

Comment: Infact,I wanna control clicked border name/Uid  in UserControlMainScreen_brd_SBE_MouseDown function @ViVi

Answer (score -1):

I solved.Problem is  in MainWindow().I added MouseDown to uAnaEkran.But I should have added mousedown to  uAnaEkran.brd_SBE and uAnaEkran.brd_BTES.Answer is below:

```
uAnaEkran.brd_SBE.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(UserControlMainScreen_brd_SBE_MouseDown);
uAnaEkran.brd_BTES.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(UserControlMainScreen_brd_BTES_MouseDown);
```